# ¿Es posible cambiar la meta etiqueta description de una página de forma dinámica para fines de SEO?

Tags: javascript, html, seo, meta-tags

Estoy intentando una página web basada en una plantilla fija y el contenido se presenta de forma dinámica en un contenedor, traído desde el servidor vía Ajax, sin recarga de la página. Todo eso funciona bien.

Pero yo quiero modificar también el `meta description` de la página según cada contenido. Quiero hacer esto para que cuando la página se indexe por el buscador ponga la meta etiqueta adecuada.

Este es el código que estoy intentando, en el `done` de mi petición Ajax:

```
var _desc="Mi descripción obtenida del nuevo contenido (dinámico) de la página";
document.getElementsByTagName('meta')["description"].content = _desc;
/* Prueba */
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('meta')["description"].content);
```

En la consola yo puedo ver el contenido esperado, pero la meta etiqueta no cambia, sigue siendo la inicial si exploro el código fuente:

```
  <meta name="description" content="%description%">
```

Si hago una prueba con el rastreador de Google lo mismo, no cambia la meta etiqueta.

¿Hay alguna forma de hacer esto de forma dinámica desde el cliente?

Comment: entiendo que el código fuente no cambiaría por más que lo cambies con javascript. Creo que la única manera posible, es que, desde backend asignes el meta description antes de cargar la página

Comment: @L.Ronquillo el `title` que es algo más genérico sí lo estoy cambiando desde el backend en la primera carga de la página, pero el contenido dinámico no, pues precisamente la idea es no recargar la página cada vez.

Comment: @A.Cedano la indexación se realiza por `URL`. Esto quiero decir, que si a los distintos contenidos se puede llegar por una `URL` diferente, entonces, lo ideal es que la página inicialmente ya tenga el "valor" correspondiente (_sino todos los enlaces tendrían contenido duplicado_). Llenarlos después de que cargar la página no es lo ideal, pero hoy por hoy los `bots` ejecutan `JS`

Comment: @Marcos no sé si mi punto de partida es erróneo, pero lo que quiero es simplificar, presentando algo así como una aplicación web de página única donde el usuario interactúe desde la misma interfaz, presentando el contenido dinámicamente en un contenedor (es algo así como un dashboard). Las URLs serían secuenciales, algo como `/01/02`, `01/02` ... `12/30`, `12/31` y por cada URL quiero que el rastreador guarde un `description` propio. La idea es esa, no sé si estoy errado en eso.

Comment: @A.Cedano, no, errado no estas, es lo que se conoce como `SPA`. Mi comentario apuntaba a que si es `SEO` el foco, entonces **SI** debería cambiar el contenido de la página (_inclusive el valor de los `meta`_) dependiendo del enlace que un usuario utilice para entrar a la web. No importa la estructura html que se descargue inicialmente (_o lo que se vea cuando ves en el código fuente_) ya que, como mencione anteriormente, los `Bots` ejecutan `JS`.

Comment: Gracias @Marcos, cuando pueda investigaré sobre SPA. Me parece una aproximación interesante poder manejar contenido dinámico sin consumir tantos recursos y poder adaptar eso también al SEO. Descubrí hoy mismo características que no conocía, [por ejemplo esto](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/History/pushState), queriendo cambiar la URL dinámicamente. Supongo que los navegadores van mejorando e incorporando nuevas funcionalidades para facilitar este tipo de cosas.